# Connection reset message from JMeter

Tags: iis, jmeter

When i ran my test I got the below error no the response section of View Result Tree.

I was testing a IIS server.

Is this Connection reset created by JMeter of was it done IIS server.

How do you interpret this error message.

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:166)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:90)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:281)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:92)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:61)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:289)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:252)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:300)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:715)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:520)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:475)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:295)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: How many threads (users) in your test plan? Did you set 'keep alive' in you http sampler?

Comment: it is single thread and it ran for 3hours and during that time the message happened only twice. and Keep alive is turned on. the system from which jmeter runs is a quad core 4 gb ram

Comment: I supposed it happens because server can't handle large load. By some reason server resets connection but it is not fail of JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 3 possibles reasons:

- Most probable cause : Your server (meaning web servers handling request and any components after them) is not handling the load correctly and slowing down, monitor the system and check
- You have exhausted your injector ephemeral ports , you need to adjust your OS TCP settings to increase port range
- You're running load test in GUI mode with a View Results Tree in test, this is bad practice as GC will happen frequently possibly triggering Stop The World leading to this. As per best-practices use NON GUI mode:

  - https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html
  - https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/